# Approximation Property

Tags: banach-spaces

It seems to be a folk result that l_infinity has the approximation property, even the bounded approximation property, and also, I think, even the so-called propery pi (approximation property) of Lindenstrauss.

This is alluded to in a few texts, but I cannot seem to find the proof, which is presumably obvious.

Does anyone have a reference or an easy solution?

Cheers,

R. Fry

Answer (score 11):

Partition the measure space into finitely many sets and consider the span of their indicator functions.  This space is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_\infty^n$ for appropriate $n$ and hence is the range of a norm one projection.  Index the partitions by refinement to get a net of norm one finite rank projections that converge strongly to the identity.

Comment: Dear Prof Johnson,

Thank you for the fast response. I am co-supervising a Masters student who needed an answer quickly so he could include it in his thesis which is to be handed in tomorrow!

Cheers,